# Renaming of class property that is marked with a DataMemberAttribute

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, datacontractserializer, datacontract

Actually i have a class like this

```
[DataContract]
public class Item : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    public virtual ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Item()
        : this(String.Empty, String.Empty)
    { }

    public Item(string id, string name)
    {
        ID = id ?? String.Empty;
        Name = name ?? String.Empty;
    }
}
```

You can easily serialize and deserialize it. But now comes the hard part:

I have to rename the property `Name` to `FullName` and every new xml serialized file should come out with the `FullName` while it is still possible to read in the old files.

To get the new property name out into a new file is quite easy. Just rename the property and you're done.

For compatibility i would mark the new property name with `[DataMember(Name="Name")]` but in this case if i write this class back into a file i got the old name written.

So exists there something in the `DataContract` where i can mark my property `FullName` maybe twice like

```
[DataMember(Name="Name")]
[DataMember]
public string FullName { get; set}
```

or is there any other mechanism how i can show that both values can be written into this, but only one will come out on writing back?

The only way i can imagine of would be to create a class `LegacyItem` which has no functions or something like this, but fulfills the old `DataContract`. Additionally some kind of implicit/explicit operator to convert my `LegacyItem` into an `Item`. Last but not least on deserializing i have to make some tests (maybe just a simple `try/catch`) to find out what class i should tell the `DataContractSerializer` to read in the file.

So even if this approach would be possible it sounds a little bit overcomplicated for this task and i'm wondering if there isn't something already available within the framework that would make this task a little bit easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind having a little obsolete code in your class (which anyway would be less code than the entire second class that you suggested) then you can do this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Item : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    public virtual ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Name", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    private string _obsoleteName { get { return null; } set { if(value != null) FullName = value; } }

    [DataMember]
    public string FullName {get; set;}

    public Item()
        : this(String.Empty, String.Empty)
    { }

    public Item(string id, string name)
    {
        ID = id ?? String.Empty;
        FullName = name ?? String.Empty;
    }
}
```

The old XML can be read in, and on deserialize will properly assign to your new property. Then when serializing, only the new property will be serialized as FullName via the set accessor. When serializing, the old property always returns null, and is not event emitted to the serialized XML.

Also you can mark the obsolete property as private so that it is not visible outside of the class.

A couple of tips going forward, I prefer to not use automatic property for `DataMember` properties. In fact I usually mark the backing field as the `DataMember`. It is probably best to ALWAYS include the optional `Name` parameter for the `DataMember` attribute. I confess I do not always do this myself, but it is a good practice, because then you don't accidentally break your contract if you Refactor -> Rename a property or field in Visual Studio.

UPDATE

The OP Oliver suggested another solution himself ... here is what that looks like for those interested.

```
[DataContract]
public class Item : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    public virtual ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Name", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    private string _obsoleteName;

    [DataMember]
    public string FullName {get; set;}

    public Item()
        : this(String.Empty, String.Empty)
    { }

    public Item(string id, string name)
    {
        ID = id ?? String.Empty;
        FullName = name ?? String.Empty;
    }

    [OnDeserialized]
    void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        if(_obsoleteName != null && FullName == null)
        {
            //upgrade old serialized object to new version
            //by copying serialized Name field to newer FullName
            FullName = _obsoleteName;

            //set _obsoleteName to null so that it stops serializing
            _obsoleteName = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First thanks for answering this old question. I also already decorate only the backing fields with the data member attribute and the name parameter. Currently i also use some kind of obsolete field, but don't use its setter to redirect. Instead i add a `OnDeserialized` method to do the *translation* into the new structure. So i have better control over the order in which the fields are set or can easier call some internal helper methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the `IExtensibleDataObject` interface and the corresponding `ExtensionDataObject` field.  It will require some custom code to make it work properly, but will help resolve your issue.

Comment: as you can see i already used the `ExtensionDataObject` to allow round-tripping. But i couldn't find any informations about how to access the data within it. If you take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.extensiondataobject.aspx) you'll see there is nothing available to get the data out of it (or am i missing something?)